# Degree symbol is not displaying correctly in XML file by using TXML Document object in Delphi XE7

Tags: xml, delphi, utf-8, delphi-xe7

[image: Please see the difference in the degree symbol]Please refer The code I have provided below.

```
****XMLDoc.Active := True;
  XMLDoc.Options := [doNodeAutoCreate, doNodeAutoIndent];
  XMLDoc.Version := '1.0';
  XMLDoc.Encoding := 'utf-8';****
```

**?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?** This is the **expected** result when I open the XML file. But it is not showing ***encoding="UTF-8"*** in the XML file. Because of which I think the degree symbol is not properly displayed in the XML file.(as it is not able to encode).

I changed UTF-8 to UTF-16,But when I tried to open the XML file it showed the  error message like **Switch from current encode to specified encode not supported**.  I guess there is some encoding problem in RAD Studio XE7 because for previous version ( Delphi XE5) it was working fine. Please give me some suggestions.

Below I am providing the sample code.

```
XMLDocument1:= TXMLDocument.create(nil);
    XMLDocument1.Active := True;
    XMLDocument1.Version :='1.0';
    XMLDocument1.Encoding :='UTF-8';
        XMLDocument2:= TXMLDocument.create(nil);
    XMLDocument2.Active := True;
    XMLDocument2.Version :='1.0';
    XMLDocument2.Encoding :='UTF-8';          

  { Add new child. This will become the document element.
    If the document element already exists, then an exception is raised. }
  //LNode := XMLDocument1.AddChild('Airbus');
  LNode := XMLDocument1.CreateElement('TestElement', '101°F (38.33°C)');
  XMLDocument1.DocumentElement := LNode;

  { Display document content. }

    XMLDocument1.SaveToFile('c:\mk1.xml');
{if we take xmldocuments.xml.text method is not taking “Encoding=’UTF-8’}
    XMLDocument2.LoadFromFile ('c:\mk1.xml');
    **strsampletext:= XMLDocument2.XML.text; //Here I am not getting "Encoding='UTF-8". and the string "strsampletext" passed as a parameter**. If I write "strsampletext" into another XML file I can't view Degree Symbol correctly when I view in IE.
```

After loading the saved XML, the encoded UTF-8 is not taking.

Comment: Can you show the code where you write the XML file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Not just here, but *everywhere* in life, a good problem description goes like this: "I did *X*. I expected to see *Y*, but I got *Z* instead." What you've posted so far doesn't include *X* at all, and you've only barely touched *Y* and *Z*. Please [edit] your question to include the necessary details.

Comment: I edited the question and provided the necessary details as well. Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Please provide a complete program. Nobody here wants to spend their time trying to re-create your program. Please add a small, cut down complete program. Imagine for a minute that we have other things to do and would like to help you, but do so in as little time as possible.

Comment: I have provided a sample code which i hope will help you to understand the issue and find a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your edits, they helped

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong here that I can reproduce. Consider this program, based on your code:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Xml.XMLIntf, Xml.XMLDoc, Winapi.ActiveX;

procedure Main;
var
  XMLDocument1, XMLDocument2: IXMLDocument;
  LNode: IXMLNode;
begin
  XMLDocument1 := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  XMLDocument1.Active := True;
  XMLDocument1.Version := '1.0';
  XMLDocument1.Encoding := 'UTF-8';
  XMLDocument2 := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  XMLDocument2.Active := True;
  XMLDocument2.Version := '1.0';
  XMLDocument2.Encoding := 'UTF-8';
  LNode := XMLDocument1.CreateElement('TestElement', '101°F (38.33°C)');
  XMLDocument1.DocumentElement := LNode;
  XMLDocument1.SaveToFile('c:\desktop\mk1.xml');
  XMLDocument2.LoadFromFile('c:\desktop\mk1.xml');
  Writeln(XMLDocument2.Encoding);
end;

begin
  CoInitialize(nil);
  Main;
  Readln;
end.
```

The output of this program, when compiled by XE7 update 1, 32 bit, is:

```
UTF-8
```

The file that is saved is encoded with UTF-8. This is a screenshot from Notepad++ when I load the file:

[image]

Note that the degree symbol is displayed correctly, and has clearly been interpreted as you intend. And note also the encoding reported in the bottom right of the window. Exactly as expected, UTF-8 without a BOM.

You have mis-diagnosed there to be a problem where in fact there is none.

---

Regarding your update, you seem now to be asking about `XML.Text`. This is a Delphi `string` and as such it is always encoded as UTF-16. All Delphi strings are encoded that way. The XML document encoding applies when the document is streamed. So, when you save to a stream or a file, then the encoding comes into play.

If you decide that you wish to save the XML content yourself, behind the back of the XML document object, then you need to take care to use the write encoding. So what is happening to you is that your code, which we still cannot see, is using the wrong encoding. Were you to save `XML.Text` to a file encoded as UTF-8 then all would be well. The problem is that you are saving with a different encoding. Most likely you are saving using the ANSI encoding.

So perhaps your code runs like this:

```
Memo1.Lines.Text := XMLDocument1.XML.Text;
Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(...);
```

This will fail because the default encoding when saving a `TStrings` is ANSI.

Comment: Thank you for your time . However I am getting problem when I write XMLDocument2.XML.Text in to some XML file and getting error when view the xml file in the IE. Please refer the modified code. Please try to open in any browser(IE/Chrome)

Comment: You've completely changed the question! I'll update the answer.